# Compression middleware order in express

Tags: node.js, express

Express API docs for `app.use()` say:

> Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of middleware inclusion is important.

Then, I see code like this all over the place:

```
import compression from 'compression';
import api from './api';
// some code 
app.use(compression() );
// some more code 
app.use(api);
```

Where `api` is the router which does `res.send()` calls.

As I see, compression middleware is registered before sending respose. Then how does it compress response? Is there some kind of hook to register callback after `res.send()` call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compression middleware is executed sequentially, but it's overloading the `res.write` `res.on` and `res.end` functions. So when the api will call those later, it wil run the compression code.

ref : https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/93586e75a0a1c5bbfd353c4cec1cfcee2e52adde/index.js#L78